# UIWebView crash on LocalStorage import since iOS10.3.0

Tags: ios, uiwebview

We use UIWebView to load remote html, it works well for a long time. Recently, we get the following crash on fabric, it only happens on iOS 10.3.0 and above.

It crash on StorageThread when Webkit try to import LocalStorage. Does any one also encouter such issue, or is there any hint to prevent it?

Crash log

> ## 21. Crashed: WebCore: LocalStorage
>
> 1. WebKitLegacy                   0x18a00a828 WebKit::StorageAreaImpl::importItems(WTF::HashMap, WTF::HashTraits > const&) + 50
> 2. WebKitLegacy                   0x18a00bc6c WebKit::StorageAreaSync::performImport() + 336
> 3. WebKitLegacy                   0x18a00f370 WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 108
> 4. JavaScriptCore                 0x1880cef7c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
> 5. JavaScriptCore                 0x1880cee8c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
> 6. libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1832b168c _pthread_body + 240
> 7. libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1832b159c _pthread_body + 282
>      7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1832aecb4 thread_start + 4

Comment: this also reported in webkit bug tracker: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=175928

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove `localStorage.setItem` in your remote html when you're in app .